# Fixed textbox on only the first page of report in page footer

Tags: ms-access-2007

Is there a way to fix a textbox in the page footer on only the first page in a MS Access report?

Answer (score 2):

In the OnFormat event of the page footer, use something like this:

```
textbox.Visible=(Me.Page=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't even have to use the OnFormat event.  In the Report Properties, set the 'Page Footer' property to 'Not with Rpt Ftr'.  This is equivalent to setting Report.PageFooter = 2 in event code and it suppresses the Page Footer on the Report Footer (with the Report Footer printed on a new page).

EDIT:  I just realized this may not work for you.  It did for me because I just didn't want the page footer to print on the report footer page.